# Add another intellij project from diffrent repository to main project

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I want to add another intellij project as intellij module to existing main project.
Project is available in other github repository than main project.
And I want add some configuration to main project that clones it on downloading latest changes and adds automatically second project to main project.

Is it possible to do and how?

I don't want to have situation that every developer in my team has to clone repo.

Answer (score 0):

You just **need to add the dependency** of the project that you want in your current project. You need to do this in the `pom.xml` file of your current project.

Let's say you want to import the project with the group-id `com.abc` and artifact id as `sample.artifact.id` with the version `1.0.0`, then the dependency that you should add in your pom.xml will look something like this.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample.artifact.id</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```